# removing some files from generator-angular-fullstack generated endpoint

Tags: angularjs, generator

I am new to the generator-angular-fullstack. I generated an endpoint witht he following endpoint command:

```
 yo angular-fullstack:endpoint message
 [?] What will the url of your endpoint be? /api/messages
```

and the files generated are:

```
 server/api/message/index.js
 server/api/message/index.spec.js
 server/api/message/message.controller.js
 server/api/message/message.integration.js
 server/api/message/message.model.js  (optional)
 server/api/message/message.events.js (optional)
 server/api/message/message.socket.js (optional)
```

so if i want to remove the message.events.js and message.socket.js, how can i do that? I actually did remove these two file by just using `rm`, but when i run the project, i got error:

```
 module.js:327
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module '../api/message/message.socket'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at onConnect (socketio.js:20:3)
at Namespace.<anonymous> (socketio.js:58:5)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Namespace.emit (/Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:206:10)
at /Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:174:14
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
Stopping Express server
```

Done waiting!

Answer (score 0):

You should edit index.js file. Code depends on a version of your yoeman generator. My index.js looks like this:

```
fs
 .readdirSync(__dirname)
   .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
     file = '/' + file + '/' + file + '.model.js';
     var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
     db[model.name] = model;
});
```

which means, it takes all files except index.js. Maybe you have your files specified here explicitly.

Or if you want to remove enpdoint, you can just edit your routes.js and remove or coment a line with your route, probably it looks like this:

```
app.use('/api/messages', require('./api/message'));
```